# return value to many views in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a really simple question, Its about how I can return a value to many views in laravel, or just make it global so i can use it in many views.
I'll explain more, I have a function in the **Message Controller** that render the messages from database to a view page called **message.blade.php**

```
public function index(){
  $listmsg = Message::where('idReceiver', Auth::id())->orderBy('idMess','desc')->get();

  return view('message', ['messages' => $listmsg]);
}
```

And on my master page ( app.blade.php ), I have a menu, in this menu I want to display the number of the unread messages, I tried this even I know it's impossible because my function return to the **message.blade.php**

```
@if(!$messages->isEmpty())
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">
    {{ $messages->count() }}
</span>
@endif
```

Notice that the **message.blade.php** extends the master page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create **View Composer** and pass data through it.

**Laravel 5**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function boot()
{
    // Using class based composers...
    View::composer(
        'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
    );

    // Using Closure based composers...
    View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
        //
    });

    // Passing multiple data to multiple views
    View::composer(['view1','view2','multipleviews.*'], function ($view) {

        $data1 = [];
        $var2 = 'string';

        $view->with(compact('data1','var2'));

    });
}
}
```

or you can use helper

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->share('key', 'value');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did some researches before posting my question here, and i found this solution, but i didn't really get the idea, can you explain it for me please ? (i'm talking about the first one)

Comment: I edited my answer with 3rd example, where I'm passing multiple data to multiple views. It is simple as you just pass what you need to where you need it. In first examples first composer call we're using a custom composer class for single view.

Comment: You could also use a Vue component and include the app.js in your header file, use axios to retrieve the data dynamically, But Rey's solution is good too.

Comment: Hey Polaris, i'm looking for the best solution to use, what can you suggest for me ?